# python replace spaces not affacted

Tags: python

In a web scraping I'm stuck in `replace()` function. I want to replace any spaces with dash in a string but it's not working in this sentence, but works in others. I don't know what's wrong with this sentence:

```
description = "Cooler Master    MasterLiquid Lite 240" # got this from html
#description = "hello world"
replace = description.replace('\s+', '-').replace(' ', '-')
print(replace)
#output: Cooler-Master-  MasterLiquid-Lite-240
```

**[Working Snippet](https://onlinegdb.com/pzlHzGX59)**

Comment: How do you know it's not working? See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Comment: It's called a `backslash` not a `backsplash`.

Comment: @peter-wood OP added a snippet. So I think that's the code with the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The split/join technique proposed by @Rodalm is excellent. However, for the sake of completeness, here's the *re* approach:

```
import re

description = "Cooler Master    MasterLiquid Lite 240"

print(re.sub('\s+', '-', description))
```

**Output:**

```
Cooler-Master-MasterLiquid-Lite-240
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.replace` doesn't support the use of regular expressions. If you want to search and replace regular expressions you have to import the built-in `re` module and use `re.sub` (or something similar).

But I think using regular expression here is overkill. You can just use `str.split` + `str.join`

```
description = "Cooler Master    MasterLiquid Lite 240"
replace = '-'.join(description.split())
print(replace)
```

Output:

```
Cooler-Master-MasterLiquid-Lite-240
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` and `join()` to erase unnecessary spaces, and then replace single space characters with `-` sign or whatever string you need:

```
description = "Cooler Master    MasterLiquid Lite 240"
replace = ' '.join(description.split()).replace(' ', '-')
#replace = '-'.join(description.split()) #More efficient alternative, avoiding replace()
print(replace)
```

> **Output:**

```
Cooler-Master-MasterLiquid-Lite-240
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will work as mentioned by @Rodalm

```
import re
description = "Cooler Master    MasterLiquid Lite 240"
#description = "hello world"
replace = re.sub('\s+', '-',description)
print(replace)
```